# Is type inference done from right to left?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-inference

Consider the following example:

```
public class Person
{
     public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Builder<TSource>
{
     public Builder<TSource> WithValue<TValue>(Func<TSource, TValue>, TValue value)
     {
         // ...
     }
}
```

These two lines work and run just fine:

```
Builder<Person> builder = new Builder<Person>();
builder.WithValue(p => p.Age, 20);
```

But so do these:

```
Builder<Person> builder = new Builder<Person>();
object age = "20";                                // <-- string value
builder.WithValue(p => p.Age, age);
```

Type inference is not working the way I expect it to work on the latter example.

If I specify an expression `p => p.Age`, which is `Func<Person, int>`, I expect the second argument to be constrained to an `int` type. Yet, I am able to pass an `object` just fine.

I'm guessing this is because type inference is being done from right to left. That is, `TValue` argument is being infered as an `object` and then my `Func<TSource, TValue>` expression is constrained to a `Func<Person, object>`, which `p => p.Age` satisfies just fine.

Is my assumption correct?

If so, why is type inference being done this way? I find it more natural from left to right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not order dependant at all.  The parameter `p => p.Age` is adding the constraint that whatever `TValue` is must be a type that can store an `int`.  That could be `int` or any type it inherits from, such as, say, `object`.  When you pass in `age` you're saying that `TValue` must be a type that can store an `object`.  It will then choose the most derived type that meets all of those constraints, which in this case, is `object`.  The same thing would happen if you changed the order of the parameters.

Comment: Isn't the most derived type `int` ?

Comment: @MatiasCicero The type `int` doesn't meet both constraints; it only meets one of the two constraints, since you can't store an `object` in a variable of type `int`.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's neither from left to right nor from right to left. Type inference takes the type information available in the given situation, and tries figuring out what type can be substituted so that it's compatible with all respective expressions. This is typically satisfied by the nearest common ancestor. In your case both `int` and `object` have `object` as this nearest common ancestor. However, in general the resolution may be a bit more complicated due to interfaces.